# Enumeration question - Discrete Mathematics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question I am having trouble with is:

> Suppose we have 3 A’s, 5 B’s, 7 C’s, 9 D’s, and one E, F, G, and H.
>
> **(a)** How many different arrangements of these letters are possible if I write them as a string?
>
> **(b)** If I write my ‘string’ as a loop, either around in a circle or around the outside of a cylinder (so there is not just one beginning
>   or end), how many different arrangements are possible?

I'm struggling with both parts, but so far my approach to **(a)** is:

```
C(28,3) x C(25,5) x C(20,7) x C(13,9) x C(4,1) x C(3,1) x C(2,1) x C(1,1)
```

Meaning, there are C(28,3) ways to choose the positions for 'A'. Then once they have been determined, there are C(25,5) ways to choose the positions for 'B', etc.

I got a huge number on the calculator which has made me question my working, so is this method correct?

For part **(b)**, I'm not even sure where to start. Can anybody give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer  and explanation in a) are good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sweet, thanks mate.

Comment: For part (b), you could think of it as placing the $E$ at the beginning (since there is only one of those) and arranging everything else to the right.  Once you are done arranging everything else, just glue the end to the left of $E$ to get your circle.

Comment: You are welcome. Since arrangements that are the same except for a rotation are considered the same, for b) we divide by $28$.  With other numbers of balls things can get a lot more complicated, if there are other natural symmetries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) is good
(b) **hint** think of a string tied to such a circle -- how many equivalent representations does the such a circle string have (e.g. if `abc` was in a circle, it'd be equivalent to `cab` and `bca`... what if there are repetitions?